# Is there any other way to disable encryption in console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, console, console-application

Im programming a web service based console application, and i would like to see the server's response on Wireshark. when I do Follow>TCP Stream, the output of the server is encrypted just like a SSL. Is there a way to disable such kind of encryption?
Edit: im using visual studio code, both WebService and Console app are on this.

Answer (score 0):

what determines if encryption is used or not is usually if https or http is used. So check the url you are using to access the web service, and switch to http if possible. There might be a bunch of other possible reasons. But the question does not provide enough details to determine exactly why.